# Overlay a transparent dark mask to UIImageView

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying on xcode to add a transparent dark mask on an UIImageView but without success, what i tried is to create a UIView set his width and height same to the UIImageView I created on the storyboard and then add a background color with opacity to the view
This is the code I used:

```
    UIView *darken;
    CGRect newFrame = darken.frame;
    newFrame.size.width = _image1.frame.size.width;
    newFrame.size.height = _image1.frame.size.height;
    [darken setFrame:newFrame];
    darken.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.85];
    [_image1 addSubview:darken];
```

Can someone help me understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Where is `darken` allocated/init? Did you check the value of `newFrame`? Has it (0,0) as origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the views frame correctly. The x and y values are never set. Also the view never gets initialized and you should add the view to `self.view` not to the imageView itself.
Try this instead:

```
 UIView *darken = [[UIView alloc]init];
darken.frame = _image1.frame;
//...
[self.view insertSubview:darken aboveSubview:_image1];
```

Comment: Damn how could I forgot to initialize the UIView :\ This worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah sorry couldn't accept because I had to wait 10 minutes!